# aibo Web APIを使っての開発

Tags: aibo-developer

aibo Web APIを使う時プログラミングを打つフォーマットはどこにありますか？

Comment: 申し訳ないですが、私には質問の意味がよくわかりませんでした。「プログラミングを打つ」とはどういうことでしょう？「フォーマット」とはどういうものを指しますか？具体例を挙げてもらえると助かります。

Comment: webAPI ですから、指定のURLにリクエストを送りさえすれば、どんなプログラミング言語を使ったり、ソースコードのフォーマットは自由なはずです。 / 例えば [Pythonでのサンプルコードがデベロッパーサイトのドキュメントに載っています](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89) が、こちらは参考になりますか？

Comment: わかりにくくてすみません。コードをどこに書くのかわからないんです。
pythonのコードはみなさまどこに書いて作っているのでしょうか。
皆さんのどの開発環境で作っているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo Web API は、aibo クラウドへ HTTP リクエストを行うことで
aibo に動作を行わせたり、認識を行わせたりすることができます。
特定のフォーマットはありませんので、お好きなプログラミング言語や開発環境をお使いください。

詳しくは、下記の aibo デベロッパープログラムの Web サイトをご確認ください。
Python のサンプルプログラムや、curl コマンドによる API の実行例が記載されていますのでご参照ください。

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs

> aiboデベロッパープログラム aiboを活用して新しいライフスタイルを作りませんか？

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#aibo-web-api-%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A8%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%8B

> aibo Web API の実行と実装の例

また、aibo Web APIは PC やサーバー、スマートフォンなど
インターネットにアクセス出来る任意のデバイスから実行が可能です。
デバイスによって実行可能な API の種類や実行内容に違いはありません。

上記でも解決されない場合は、aiboオーナーサポートへお問い合わせください。

https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact

> 「aiboの飼い方、ご購入前の相談など、aiboに関するすべてのお問い合わせは以下のaibo専用窓口へお問い合わせください。」

#### メールでのお問い合わせ

https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry_mail/?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_mail

> 上記リンク先において、注意事項に同意いただいた上、「同意してメールで問い合わせる」ボタンを押してください。

#### チャットでのお問い合わせ

https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry/chat.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_chat

> 上記リンク先にある「上記内容を確認して自動往々サービスを開始する」を押してください。

#### LINE でのお問い合わせ

https://www.sony.jp/support/inquiry_line.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_line

> LINE公式アカウントから、お問い合わせをいただけます。
> リンク先にある「友だち追加」ボタンをクリックするか、「QRコード」を読み取ってください。

また、Stackoverflow への質問はプログラミングのことに限定していただきますようお願いいたします。
詳しくはこちらをご参照ください。
https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact#devevisu
・質問の例
「〇〇のプログラムを実行したいのですが、どうすればできますか？」
「APIでエラーが発生します。原因は何でしょうか？」

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: 「お好きなプログラミング言語や開発環境」のところですが、
pythonでgoogle.colaboratory　もしくは　JavamでEclipse を使おうと思っていますが、できますか？

Comment: 個々の開発環境につきましては、申し訳ありませんがお答えいたしかねます。

HTTP リクエストを行うことのできるプログラム言語や開発環境であれば、aibo Web API をご利用いただけます。

実行方法につきましては、下記の aibo デベロッパープログラムの Web サイトをご確認ください。
Python のサンプルや、curl コマンドによる API の実行例が記載されています。

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs